# How to get the value of a cell which is next to a cell containing specific text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet which has cells with the text "Test Result" and the cell next to "Test Result" contains either Pass or Fail. I want to count the number of Pass and Fail instances which are mentioned next to the cell containing "Test Result".

*NOTE: The column which contains the Pass or Fail that I want to count, has other Pass/Fail instances as well. So, I want to get the Pass or Fail value which is ONLY next to the a cell containing text "Test Result".*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COUNTIFS function to accomplish this. If your data was in columns A and B, this is how you would enter the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Test Result",B:B,"Pass")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is predictably structured, and you are only trying to return a single result- I would go with @Scott Craner's answer of using VLookup or Index/Match.

If your data is predictably structured, and you want to count across many results, you should probably be considering using 2 sumifs functions (one for pass and one for fail).

If your data is not predictably structured, you can consider using an array of these sumifs functions to each check a particular column against its offset column, or you can accomplish this using VBA, but it's hard for me to suggest the exact code without seeing how the data is structured/unstructured. (Your explanation of the sheet and data layout is a bit vague)